# Is there any OOTB way of determining when a list was updated?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

What I'm referring to specifically is when anything about a list (or library) has changed, such as items added, removed, updated, list structure changed, etc.

What I was hoping for was some way to use the built in web services (or object model) to query for a "timestamp" that would indicate last time anything about the list was changed.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple OOTB solution is to create an alert for this list and configure the alert to send you an alert if anything is changed with the list.

Please reference this helpful link that will outline the steps for creating and setting these alerts.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-an-alert-or-subscribe-to-an-rss-feed-HA010378197.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the object model property splist.LastChangeToken

More about it...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spchangetoken.aspx

Comment: This one looks promising. Does this log changes to the "settings" of a library or list as well?  Like when a column is added or removed, or the versioning is enabled or disabled?  In other words, anything about a list, not just the items within the list.

Comment: Change token is for an item, list , web  , site and ContentDatabase.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of SPList [LastItemModifiedDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.lastitemmodifieddate.aspx) and [LastItemModifiedDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.lastitemmodifieddate.aspx) properties

```
public static void PrintListProperties(SPList list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list.LastItemDeletedDate); // returns the date and time that an item, field, or property of the list was last deleted 
    Console.WriteLine(list.LastItemModifiedDate); //returns the date and time that an item, field, or property of the list was last modified
}
```